# My on click event is not firing- have checked previous answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to handle the click of a button in javascript/jquery.  I am having an issued getting the trigger to fire.  I have gleaned previous questions in hoping to find an answer, but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Below is my code to show one button and handle the click of the button. When the user clicks the button, the code should be catching the click event, but it is not.

I have debugged the code and set a breakpoint on the on click event.  The breakpoint is never hit. I have trimmed the code down to a minimum example.

What am I missing regarding getting the on click event to fire?

I have included the entire file, including the html, in case I am missing something there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= HOST_ADDRESS ?>/stylesheets/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<STYLE TYPE="TEXT/CSS">
    .clear { clear: both; }
    html {
        background: #e9e9e9;
        font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    body { 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #btn_area {
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
    }
    .ui-widget-header {
        border: 0px !important;
    }
    .ui-button {
        width:110px !important;
        height:30px !important;
        font-size: 16px;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
</STYLE>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#header_wrapper').addClass('ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');
    
        $('#send1').on('click', function() {
            aaa = true;
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
    <div>
        Test Window
    </div>
    <div class="button_wrapper">
        <div id="btn_area">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="button" id="send1" name="send1" style="font-size:large" class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' value="Send">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried running the code in a LAMP stack and a MAMP stack and get the same results.

Comment: The function is being run OK on a click. Try putting a console.log or an alert in there and you will see the function has been entered. It doesn’t seem to do anything though other than set a non global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `aaa` in your script? - Anyway, I've copied your code to a snippet below, as you can see the click is being received.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
        $('#send1').on('click', function() {
                    //RUN YOUR FUNCTION IN HERE.
        });
    });
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
//declare aaa
    var aaa = false
        $('#send1').on('click', function() {
                    //aaa will be true after button is clicked
                    aaa = true;
                    if (aaa = "true") {
                    console.log('aaa is now true')
                    }
        });
    });
```

```css
.clear { clear: both; }
    html {
        background: #e9e9e9;
        font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    body { 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #btn_area {
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
    }
    .ui-widget-header {
        border: 0px !important;
    }
    .ui-button {
        width:110px !important;
        height:30px !important;
        font-size: 16px;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="#header_wrapper">
        Test Window
    </div>
    <div class="button_wrapper">
        <div id="btn_area">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="button" id="send1" name="send1" style="font-size:large" class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' value="Send">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: aaa is just a variable.  I am setting a breakpoint on that line of code, and I am never hitting the breakpoint.  I will try your console log and see if I get that.

Comment: See the updated snippet. - I am now setting aaa as false and then when the button is clicked, changing it to true. Perhaps, this will set you on the right track?

Comment: I am getting the console log entry.  Apparently the debuggers on Safari and Chrome are are not stopping on the breakpoint I set.  Not sure why.  I should have thought about the console log.  - Thanks

Comment: No problem, I see that you're new here. If this helped, please mark as correct by clicking the checkmark ✅  and upvoting. Thanks!